# Webform error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have created a new webform in Drupal for membership signups.  When I try and test the form I get the error message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Other forms with Civi integration are working fine, so there is an issue with just this specific form.  The only difference I can find is that I'm trying to create memberships on this form.

Here is the setup for the membership - it is a free membership
[image]

Any thoughts as to why this one form would not be working? Thanks

Comment: Can you check your Drupal logs to find more details about the error?

Comment: CRM_Core_Exception: 'Provincial' is not a valid option for field custom_23 in civicrm_api3()

Comment: does that explain it enough for you. says there is a custom field id 23 in use but not happy with the options on the form

Comment: not really, the list of options is being pulled directly from Civi, so how can the options on the form not be accepted?  It is set to Live Options, the options in Civi are identical to the options on the form

Comment: Nevermind - somehow a word had been entered into the "Value" field under "Title" - removing the word fixed the issue